# Cabal source bundle and haddock documentation

Tags: haskell, cabal

I try to test the upload of a cabal bundle to HackageDB. When I test it on the hackage website, it all goes fine *but* the output that it presents to me contains only the content page and there is no further link to the actual module documentation.

Now, I do not know if that means that the documentation could not be build (cabal haddock runs fine and builds the correct html on my test systems) or that I need to somehow manually include the html into the package or ... maybe build the distributable package with more options in cabal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The job that builds the documentation for new packages on [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org) runs only every couple of hours, not continuously. So it usually takes a few hours between uploading a package and the appearance of its documentation on hackage.

There's nothing to do except wait for it.

Occasionally, the job dies, and needs to be manually restarted, if no documentation is generated within 24 hours, you could poke the hackage administrator(s), send an email to them (or haskell-cafe) then.